# Can you put plants in the ground in their original containers to protect from voles?

Tags: flowers, pests, containers

We have a bit of a vole issue and I bought a wire mesh for my bulbs but I plant over a hundred annuals each year so that's a bit labor intensive to do for everything.

Comment: What have you noticed in terms of damage by voles?